# Full blocking join in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use pyspark to dedupe a database and as part of the pipeline I want to create a dataframe from two identical left and right dataframes. These have a shared index.

Initially I was lazy and just used a CROSS JOIN, but that results in duplication of joins (as left to right is the same as right to left). But I now need to optimise the code a bit and I am left wondering what is the best way to achieve this type of join. Can anyone suggest anything?

```py
l_df = spark.createDataFrame([('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',)], ['l_idx'])
r_df = spark.createDataFrame([('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',)], ['r_idx'])

l_df.createOrReplaceTempView('l_df')
r_df.createOrReplaceTempView('r_df')

block_df = spark.sql('''
SELECT *
FROM l_df
CROSS JOIN r_df
''')

block_df.show()
```

This results in all combinations.

However I am looking for..

```
A B
A C
A D
B C
B D
C D
```

only

Thanks jxc!
Solved with your suggestion!

Comment: add a WHERE clause: `SELECT * FROM l_df CROSS JOIN r_df WHERE l_df.l_idx < r_df.r_idx`

Comment: Thank you, thats a great idea, however it gives me the error...     Can't extract value from r_idx#63: need struct type but got string; line 7 pos 25

Comment: can you post the error message? BTW. you need to enclose the SQL in your code: `block_df = spark.sql('''.......''')`

Answer (score 0):

It will work. Please find below.

```
>>> bdf = spark.sql("select * from l_df CROSS JOIN r_df WHERE l_df.l_idx < r_df.r_idx")

>>> bdf.show()


+-----+-----+
|l_idx|r_idx|
+-----+-----+
|    A|    B|
|    A|    C|
|    A|    D|
|    B|    C|
|    B|    D|
|    C|    D|
+-----+-----+
```